# Why Facebook block my auth login url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-app-requests

i am using free `.co.cc` domain name. 
i used that domain to enable auth with facebook.
but when i run my script it redirect to facebook and show error:

```
Error
This URL Is Blocked: The URL "http://xxxxxxxxx.cu.cc/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook"
has been blocked from Facebook.
```

so i want to know, does facebook URL like this and why ?
is it problem with my free domain name or with my scripts ?

---

i am using hybridauth for this. it works with every thing but not with facebook login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - as the error states, the URL has been blocked. It does not appear to be related to your scripts.

Of course, if your scripts were doing strange things that Facebook didn't approve of, like violating their TOS, then they might have blocked your specific URL. I don't believe this is the case because you mentioned that you are using a free domain service - it would be conceivable that Facebook would want to block such "open" services in order to prevent possible security issues.

Comment: thanks @Lix actually i did'nt such a violation. only thing i did is just replace my app id and app screct. because i am using hybridauth for this task, and it works with all, but facebook. :(

Comment: maybe all .co.cc domains are blocked because they're free and easy to spam?

Comment: @igy - that was my first suspicion. It's not unlike the free SSL certificate services which are also blocked by certain providers. Do you know of any other cases of domain wide blocking?